# how to work with php equalto operator(relational operator)

Tags: php, operators, php-5.6

I have a big confusion over equal to operators(==.===), below I mentioned php code where checking condition that string "all" equal to numeric 0. But it returns true at double equal to `("all"==0)`, but not with others:

```
<?php    
    var_dump("all"==0);
    var_dump("all"=="0");
    var_dump("all"==="0");
    var_dump("all"===0);    
?>
```

*Output:*

```
bool(true) 
bool(false)
bool(false) 
bool(false)
```

for all the condition the answer should be false. but why "all"==0 is true. can anyone explain?

Comment: When 0 is alive it is numeric and when 0 is in "(double quote) it defines as a string.

Comment: please under the question before marking duplicate. and give a correct solution and refrence for this before marking duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

```
=== is Identical operator which performs a 'typesafe comparison'.
```

That means that it will only return true if both operands have the same type and the same value.

Comment: The question has already been flagged with three duplicates. Please read the comments

Comment: yes, i agree but when i checked the condition of double equal to `("all" ==0)` it should be `false`.. instead of that  getting `true` as result. can you please explain me the reason?

This question may duplicate but no one is explain why `("all"==0)` is `true` .. in that question i mentioned 4 possibilities output. for all condition should be false is output. except ` "all"==0`

i'm not good in English. i apologise for any grammatical mistake.